# Why can I not see my variants with chromoqc?

Tags: r

I have a vcf file with 20 variants in chromosome 1 that I would like to visualise using vcfR.
What I am doing is the following:

```
#Read in my mouse genome and filter and rename chromosome 1
ref_genome <- ape::read.FASTA("mouse_genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna.primary_assembly.fa", type = "DNA")
ref_genome_chr1 <- ref_genome[ grep("GRCm38:1:", names(ref_genome))]
names(ref_genome_chr1) <- "1"
ref_genome_chr1 <- as.matrix(ref_genome_chr1)

#Read in my vcf file and also a mouse gff annotation file
vis_test_vcf <- read.vcfR("test_data/filter_chr1_test.recode.vcf", verbose = TRUE)
mouse_gff <- read.table("mouse_genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.102.gff3", sep="\t", quote="")

#Generate chromR object
chrom_test <- create.chromR(name="chr1_test", vcf=vis_test_vcf, seq=ref_genome_chr1, ann=mouse_gff, verbose=TRUE)

#Now try and plot this
chromoqc(chrom_test)
```

When I head() etc the various objects they look ok and I don't get any warnings about chromosome names not matching or anything. However, the plot is missing the "Variants per site" track, which is all I care about...[I get this plot, whereby it's not showing the Variants per site. It's also not showing the DP and MQ but I'm not so worried about that at this stage...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMXcM.png)

Has anyone had a similar issue? I would be grateful for any pointers!
Kind regards
Cora

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just found the answer!

I needed to use
`proc.chromR()`
to process my chromR object, now it has plotted the variants.
Still need to work out the DP and MQ stuff..